# What is module-alias tag in jboss-deployment-structure.xml in Wildfly ? and usage of this tag?

Tags: xml, jboss, module, wildfly, wildfly-8

can anyone explain me the usage of module-alias tag in boss-deployment-structure.xml in Wildfly ?

and with an example scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that one .war could depend on another .war to control the order that Wildfly deploys the .war's.  By specifying a module alias, a .war could refer to another .war using the alias instead of the fill .war filename.

For an example of this, see [Wildfly/JBoss deployment startup order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32598958/132374)

This *almost* worked for me... however, because there was a dependency, extra classes were being loaded into memory (see the link for details).  I just wanted to control startup order.

This is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

Module alias tag is to avoid the dynamic version taken into consideration. For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
   <deployment>
      <module-alias name="test.project"/>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

my actual war name is test.project.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war. Since my version of the war keep on changing, i don't want to take the version into consideration. so i am avoiding that by mentioning it inside the module-alias tag.